# How to convert varchar into usable date in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date

I am having an issue converting an nvarchar into a date.

The column title is `DOS` and the dates are formatted like `05-03-2012`.

I am trying to convert to a date so I can filter in the `where` clause.

I have seen explanations using `CONVERT(datetime, DOS, 101)` but I am not sure where this would go? In the select? In the where clause? Is this the best method to convert varchar into date?

```
SELECT BedSize
    ,avg(contributionmargin) AS ContributionMargin
FROM Summary
WHERE DOS > '06-30-2016'
GROUP BY bedsize
HAVING avg(contributionmargin) > 10000
ORDER BY contributionmargin DESC
```

In this example the `where` clause is just looking at the '06' in the date and selecting values that are greater than 06, so the results include:

- 07/01/2013
- 07/02/2009
- 08/31/2009
- 09/25/2012
- 11/03/2016
- 12/03/2008

The problem is that the years are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

Add a new datetime column (let's suppose DOSDate) in the table and then run this query

```
update mytable set DOSDate = STR_TO_DATE(DOS,'%m-%d-%Y')
```

But future inserts in mytable will also needs to be converted and stored in DOSDate` column.

Option 2:

If you cannot add a new column, use this in `where` clause

```
select * from mytable where STR_TO_DATE(DOS,'%m-%d-%Y') >  p_mydate
```

Since you have not provided a query, the above is a sample query to illustrate the point.

UPDATE

Initially you marked your question related to MySQL.  For SQL Server you may use `CAST` or `CONVERT` instead of `STR_To_DATE`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Sorry this is meant for SQL Server 2016. I accidentally had the title as mySQL. Appologies

Comment: Your second option is what I am looking for (this is a read only database) but for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the `convert` function for SQL Server.

This code works:

```
SELECT BedSize
    ,avg(contributionmargin) AS ContributionMargin
FROM Summary
WHERE Convert(DATE, DOS, 101) > '06-30-2016'
GROUP BY bedsize
HAVING avg(contributionmargin) > 10000
ORDER BY contributionmargin DESC
```